# Check if input text is filled and display different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 input text and I want to display a div if one over 3 is filled, a different div if 2 input over 3 are filled and so on. How can I do it with javascript?

```
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" />
<input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" />
<input type="text" id="text3" name="text3" />
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
function display() {
    if ($('#text').val() != '') {
        document.getElementById('green').style.display = 'block';
    }   
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: I pasted over the code I used

Comment: Your question looks somehow confusing. I will like to know which of my responses addressed your question @Domenico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding here. @Domenico asked

> I have 3 input text and I want to display a div if one over 3 is filled, a different div if 2 input over 3 are filled and so on.

If I am not misunderstanding his statement: I think he is talking about the number of inputs that were filled and not necessarily the particular input that was filled.

Hence [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/db17mjow/):

```
#div_1, #div_2, #div_3{
    display: none;
}


<input type="text" id="text_1" name="text1" value="" />
<input type="text" id="text_2" name="text2" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="text_3" name="text3" value="" />

<div id="div_1">Only ONE input is filled</div>
<div id="div_2">Only TWO inputs are filled</div>
<div id="div_3">All THREE inputs are filled</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[id*='text']").blur(function() {
        var counter=0;
        $("input[id*='text']").each(function(ind, val){
            if($(val).val().trim()!==""){
                counter++;
            }
        });

        $("#div_1, #div_2, #div_3").hide();

        $("#div_"+counter).show(); 
    });
});
```

But if you want it the other way round, here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/07q5adrj/) too:

```
#div_1, #div_2, #div_3{
    display: none;
}


<input type="text" id="text_1" name="text1" value="" />
<input type="text" id="text_2" name="text2" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="text_3" name="text3" value="" />

<div id="div_1">Input ONE is filled</div>
<div id="div_2">Input TWO is filled</div>
<div id="div_3">Input THREE is filled</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[id*='text']").blur(function() {

        $("#div_1, #div_2, #div_3").hide();
        $("input[id*='text']").each(function(ind, val) {
            if ($(val).val().trim() !== "") {
                console.log("div_"+$(val).prop("id").split("_")[1])
                $("#div_"+$(val).prop("id").split("_")[1]).show();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: the first one, sorry! ;)

Answer (score 5):

CSS

```
#a, #b, #c {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var istext1filled = document.querySelector('input#text1').value.length>0;
var istext2filled = document.querySelector('input#text2').value.length>0;
var istext3filled = document.querySelector('input#text3').value.length>0;

if(istext1filled) {
    document.querySelector('div#a').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
if(istext2filled) {
    document.querySelector('div#b').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
if(istext3filled) {
    document.querySelector('div#c').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: Fire the JavaScript code upon the occurrence of some action - say button click. For that you will need to wrap the JavaScript code inside a function. Thanks :)

Comment: it works, but how can I do it dynamically, because when I fill inputs it doesn't work